# Where does Resources[@viewFile] get created?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm editing some CoffeeScript which is using Backbone.  I don't know much about it, so when I came across this

```
for name in Resources[@viewFile].templates
```

I was stumped.

Does anyone know what this is doing and where it's being initialised?  I've searched all over the place and there is no declaration or initialisation for the Resources object.

I should mention that @viewFile is initialised like this

```
@viewFile = arguments[0]
```

Thanks